# How can I force extension popup be X width?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, popup, width

I have width of 500px in my `body` and I've tried setting it in `html`. But after updating to chrome 30 (osx) it stop displaying wrong.

I'm not sure if google changed their API but for what I've read it doesn't seem to.

[This is what I see](http://take.ms/a2XEg2) and the console reporting it's 500px but clearly it isn't.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't say about OS X, but with Chrome 30.0.1599.101 on Windows, I am able to adjust the width of a popup (among many ways) by setting the CSS `width` property of the body. (E.g. in CSS: `body { width: 500px; }` or in JS `document.body.style.width = "500px";` both work fine.)

Comment: I've tried this already as mentioned in the question. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is your extension bootstraped or something ? Have you rried that with an extension with no other CSS at all ?

Comment: It is bootstraped but it's always been. I found that it was the number of scripts I was requiring, once I compressed all into one it got fixed. Really weird.

Comment: Pretty weird indeed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it was the number of scripts I was requiring. It doesn't make sense for me, because even if you're requiring too many scripts that don't modify the size of the window or container it shouldn't affect with the CSS.

Once I minified and compressed all js files into one, it got fixed.